# Retorno valor errado

Tags: c#, linq

Estou criando uma lista dentro de outra da seguinte forma:

```
var playerGames01 = new ObjectGamePlayerMoviments();

        playerGames01.Game = new List<Games>()
        {
           new Games
           {
               PlayerMoviment = new List<PlayersMoviments>()
               {
                    new PlayersMoviments {
                        Name = "Armando",
                        Moviment = "P"
                    },
                    new PlayersMoviments {
                         Name = "Dave",
                        Moviment = "S"
                    }
               }
           }
        };
```

E quando tento realizar um select para descobrir se existem movimentos diferentes de `P,R ou S`, ele sempre me retorna que existe 1.

Oque estou fazendo de errado ?

```
var verifyChoice = game.Game.Select(x => x.PlayerMoviment.Select(y => y.Moviment != "P" && y.Moviment != "S" && y.Moviment != "R"));
```

Ele retorna como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual [e esse um que seleciona?

Comment: @Maniero coloquei imagem na pergunta. O problema é que ele retorna Empty e consequentemente pega o valor `1,` ai estou comparando com `0`, se eu mudar a comparação para `1`, quando eu tiver um valor real ele deixará passar.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma, caso alguém um dia precise.

```
var verifyChoice = game.Game.Select(x => x.PlayerMoviment.Where(y => y.Moviment != rock && y.Moviment != paper && y.Moviment != scissors)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Era minha próxima pergunta. Se quer filtrar alguma coisa, porque usou o `Select`?

Comment: Pois como é uma Lista dentro de uma lista, com meus conhecimentos não consegui encontrar maneira de filtrar a lista filha @Maniero